# What's the reason of Broadcast Receiver not working

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I tried out many ways but my receiver is not working. I am stuck in this from long time and have tried everything possible or I can understand but didn't found solution of this problem. Please find the code below.

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cyberdashtechnologies.scanhubnt">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ScanhubNt"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            />
        <activity android:name=".support"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyReceiver

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        
        if(Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED) || Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context,location.class));
        }
        
    }
```

Can you please tell where I am doing wrong? so that issue can be resolved

Comment: Did you print log in onReceive method ? It may be your service not working

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: as Ahmed said, did you tried adding some log and checked you are getting it?

Comment: I tried starting services directly and I got data on my server but if I am trying via receiver I am not getting any data. so I think it's not working